# Getting bad request when calling Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im getting a bad request when running this code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: loginHostUri,
           method:'POST',
           headers:{
               'Accept':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           },
           extraParams:{
               grant_type:'password',
               username:username,
               password:psswd,
               client_id: consumerKey,
               client_secret: consumerSecret
           },
           success: function(response){
               Ext.Msg.alert('Info',reponse);
           }
       });
```

When i use the javascript debuger i get an error message
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load " "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the url "loginHostUri" whether it is null or not. Are you trying a cross domain request? In that case you will not be able to do that from browser (until you open the browser in unsecured mode). And Ajax requests sends parameters by "params" not "extraParams".

Comment: I just had to change extraParams to params

Answer (score 0):

on the server side (JSP) I use:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
```

and this solve the problem.